# Using Quartz2 and Bean CDI

Tags: cdi, tomcat8, quartz

I need to create a method that executes automatically whenever Tomcat starts. I followed a tutorial and could implement a method that implements org.quartz.Job, so it's working, but the problem is that it does not let me to inject a bean CDI in the method, it simply stop running without log errors.

I found out that Quartz must be integrated with something to use CDI, I've already tried DeltaSpike and it gives me errors, does anyone have any idea?

I use:

- jsf 2.2
- CDI
- Tomcat 8
- Eclipse IDE
- Maven

My job class:

```
package com.sisRastrbov.schedule;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class SchedulerJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("JSF 2 + Quartz 2 example");

    }

}
```

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- núcleo do hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>totalsat</groupId>
            <artifactId>totalsat</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- implementação do Hibernate BeanValidator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc/jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->



        <!-- implementação do entityManager da Jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mojarra (implementação do JSF 2) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- omnifaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces Biblioteca de componentes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API de servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- listener -->
             <!-- JSF 2 libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

                <!-- Tomcat 6 need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz scheduler framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz need transaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>    
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param> 
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
       <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
       <resource-env-ref-type>
          javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
       </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Main.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you even coud have add all the SpingFramework to do that :)
That should do the job:

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
@javax.ejb.Startup
public class Startup {
    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start");
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

keep it simple :)
You should think about replacing quartz with the JEE scheduler if your use case matches
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply skay, I appreciated your answer, but  I could solve the problem with apache Deltaspike.

Comment: You *don't* need deltapike to resolve this problem. You only need CDI / provided by your JEE7+ container.